# Где найти иконки для Android приложений в стиле Material?

Tags: android, design, material-design

У меня в приложении есть блок информации - `RelativeLayout`. Все работает хорошо, но дизайн просто ужасен. Дайте пару советов на счет дизайна.

Или подскажите где найти иконки в Material стиле?

Мой блок

[image: блок]

Comment: Норм дизайн, только иконку замените на одну из стандартных - она выбивается из материал стиля.

Comment: [Официальные гайдлайны по дизайну](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#)

Comment: И кстати, почитайте справку по тематике задаваемых вопросов. В нынешнем виде вопрос закроют за 5 минут.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, проблема в том, что не могу найти подходящую иконку.

Comment: Аналог вопроса на en-SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975587/where-can-i-find-and-download-material-design-icons-for-my-android-app

Comment: @Mr. Awesome Подходящие иконки делает дизайнер

Answer (score 2):

Помогло использование MaterialDesign стандартов и иконок. Ссылки:

1. [Иконки](http://materialdesignblog.com/top-10-sets-of-free-material-design-icons-for-web-designers-and-developers/)
2. [Стандарты](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-usage)
3. [Постоянно обновляемый репозиторий с иконками от гугла](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons)
4. Удобный способ их [скачать](https://www.google.com/design/icons/) с предпросмотром (тоже от гугла)

Answer (score 1):

Также существует отличный [плагин](https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin) c открытым исходным кодом для `AndroidStudio`. Позволяет выбрать цвет иконки, разрешение. Есть предпросмотр и автоматическое копирование по разным `dpi` папкам в проект.